# Warning: Error updating Text

Tags: matlab, text, matlab-gui

MATLAB gives me a warning as following:

```
Warning: Error updating Text.

Character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:
$\Theta(s) = 9.24\cdot 10^{04 }\cdot \frac{s +    0}{s^{4} +  140s^{3} + 2.35\cdot 10^{03s}^{2} + 9.24\cdot 10^{04s} +    0}$
```

I'm not sure why it is invalid syntax. I'm using the following code:

```
numericTF = struct;
symbolTF = struct;

if strcmp(vars.response_type,'Position')
    typeString = 'Theta(s)';
else
    typeString = 'Omega(s)';
end

tf4thOnum = [1 I/P];
tf4thOden = [1 (b*L+R*J)/J/L (R*b+ Kb*Km)/J/L 2*Km*P/J/L I*2*Km/J/L];
tf4thOgain = 2*Km*P/J/L;
tf4thOstr = sprintf('$\\%s = %4.3g \\cdot \\frac{s + %4.3g}{s^{4} + %4.3gs^{3} + %4.3gs^{2} + %4.3gs + %4.3g}$', typeString, tf4thOgain,tf4thOnum(2:end),tf4thOden(2:end));
tf4thOsym = '\frac{k_ak_mk_p}{JL}\cdot\frac{s+\frac{k_i}{k_p}}{s^4+\frac{bL+RJ}{JL}s^3+\frac{bR+k_bk_m}{JL}s^2+\frac{k_ak_mk_p}{JL}s+\frac{k_ik_mk_ap}{JL}}$';
```

Another function to add scientific notation:

```
function instring = cleanExps(instring)
        exps = findstr(instring,'e+');
        maxn = length(exps);
        if ~isempty(exps)
            for ii = 1:maxn
                if isempty(exps) break; end
                instring = strrep(instring,instring(exps(1):exps(1)+4),['\cdot 10^{' instring(exps(1)+2:exps(1)+4) '}']);
                exps = findstr(instring,'e+');
            end
        end
        exps = findstr(instring,'e-');
        maxn = length(exps);
        if ~isempty(exps)
            for ii = 1:maxn
                if isempty(exps) break; end
                instring = strrep(instring,instring(exps(1):exps(1)+4),['\cdot 10^{-' instring(exps(1)+2:exps(1)+4) '}']);
                exps = findstr(instring,'e-');
            end
        end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the warning message that you are trying to set the string of a [text object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) to the following (which I've broken up into multiple lines for clarity):

```
str = ['$\Theta(s) = 9.24\cdot 10^{04}\cdot \frac{s + 0}{s^{4} + 140s^{3}' ...
       ' + 2.35\cdot 10^{03s}^{2} + 9.24\cdot 10^{04s} + 0}$'];
```

There's at least one of two things going wrong here...

First, you need to make sure that the [`'Interpreter'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html#input_argument_d0e1000721) of the text object is set to `'latex'` instead of the default `'tex'`, since you are using LaTeX markup.

Second, there are two errors in the syntax of your terms, noted here:

```
'... + 2.35\cdot 10^{03s}^{2} + 9.24\cdot 10^{04s} + 0}$'
                        ^                        ^
```

Those two curly braces should be on the other side of the `s`. The first one causes your syntax error since `10^{...}^{...}` doesn't make sense. The second one just wrongly puts `s` in the exponent.

Those two errors appear to be the result of a bug in your `cleanExps` function. Every `+4` appearing in that function should be a `+3` to keep it from including one too many characters after the exponent. If you're interested, a more robust and potentially faster alternative to your function would be this one call to [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html):

```
instring = regexprep(instring, 'e([+|-]+)(\d+)', '\\cdot 10^{${setdiff($1,''+'')}$2}');
```

After fixing the bug and ensuring you are using the `latex` interpreter setting, everything should work fine. For example:

```
str = ['$\Theta(s) = 9.24\cdot 10^{04}\cdot \frac{s + 0}{s^{4} + 140s^{3}' ...
       ' + 2.35\cdot 10^{03}s^{2} + 9.24\cdot 10^{04}s + 0}$'];
hText = text(0.1, 0.5, str, 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 14);
```

[image]

Comment: It is very useful! However, i think tf4thOstr is formatted right? The problem might be the conversion between string and number?

Comment: I added the code for scientific notation of the display equation. It might be where the issue is.

Comment: @DavidLing: Yep, there was a bug in your `cleanExps` function. Updated answer with a fix.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are awesome!